# comparison of 2 ranges that may or may not have bounds

Tags: if-statement, language-agnostic, logic

The problem is quite simple, yet it is very hard to come up with a solution that is not hundreds of lines of sphagetti else-ifs.

There are 2 ranges that may or may not have bounds, if there are bounds they may be inclusive or not.

pseudocode:

```
struct bound
{
    float val
    bool inclusive
}

struct range
{
    optional<bound> lower_bound
    optional<bound> upper_bound
}
```

For example, `<3, 5]` (numbers >3 and <= 5) would be `range: { lower_bound: {3, false}, upper_bound: {5, true} }` and `[8,` (numbers >= 8) would be `range: { lower_bound: { 8, true }, upper_bound: null }`

**Given 2 ranges, decide on relation of the first range to the second (identical, subset, superset, intersect, disjoint)** (example ranges above are disjoint since no value can be both <= 5 and >= 8)

```
enum relation { identical, subset, superset, intersect, disjoint }

relation_first_to_second(range first, range second): relation
{
     // ???
}
```

The problem is that when writing the function care must be taken to handle all possible corner cases, I have made a sample chart that showcases these cases (`-` means there is no bound). We can assume that ranges are always valid themselves, in others words we can assume that (if they exist) A is always less or equal to B and X is always less or equal to Y (but we can not assume relation between: A/X A/Y B/X B/Y).

```
lower upper   lower upper   relation first to second
  -     -       -     -      identical
  -     -       -     Y      superset
  -     -       X     -      superset
  -     -       X     Y      superset
  -     B       -     -      subset
  -     B       -     Y      B=Y: identical, B<Y: subset, B>Y superset
  -     B       X     -      B<X: disjoint, B>=X: intersect
  -     B       X     Y      B<X: disjoint, X<=B<=Y: intersect, B>Y: superset
  A     -       -     -      subset
  A     -       -     Y      A<=Y: intersect, A>Y: disjoint
  A     -       X     -      A=X: identical, A<X: superset, A>X: subset
  A     -       X     Y      A>Y: disjoint, X<=A<=Y: intersect, A<X: superset
  A     B       -     -      subset
  A     B       -     Y      Y<A: disjoint, A<=Y<=B: intersect, Y>B: subset
  A     B       X     -      X<A: subset, A<=X<=B: intersect, X>B: disjoint
  A     B       X     Y      this will be complex to check...
```

Note that this chart does not take `inclusive` into consideration.

---

If you have a better idea of implementing ranges themselves - you are welcome, just don't assume that `<=3` is the same as `<4` and don't rely on the fact that unbound range can use minimum/maximum value of integer (the actual problem domain is more generic). I can't think of any better representation than a type that consists of 2 bounds (each storing value and whether it's inclusive) that may or may not exist.

---

I'm looking for a code (any language or pseudocode) as short as possible that implements `relation_first_to_second` function. This is not a code golf, but I think "shortest code solution is best answer" is very relevant for this question.

Answer (score 2):

Your representation of ranges is incomplete as it doesn't allow one to distinguish between positive and negative infinity, and thus represent an empty range as (+∞, -∞). Once you add both +∞ and -∞ to the list of allowed values, all suddenly falls into place.

You now can compare endpoints and find minimal and maximal ones. If two end points have the same finite coordinate and differ by inclusiveness, it will be convenient to regard both their minimum and maximum as exclusive.

Now the intersection of two ranges r1 and r2 will be a range from `max(r1.left, r2.left)` to `min(r1.right, r2.right)`. This result can be empty, equal to just `r1`, equal to just `r2`, equal to both, or to neither. This correspond to your disjoint, subset, superset, identical, and intersect relations.

Caveat: two empty ranges are always identical *and* disjoint at the same time, but their representation may not be *equal* (the empty range has many representations). A separate check is needed if one wants the "identical" predicate to work correctly for empty ranges.

Here's some hastily cobbled up Haskell:

```
data Point = MinusInfinity |
             Finite Double Bool |
             PlusInfinity deriving (Eq, Ord, Show)

data Range = Range { left :: Point , right :: Point } deriving (Eq, Show)

min', max' :: Point -> Point -> Point
min' (Finite p1 i1) (Finite p2 i2) | p1 == p2 = Finite p1 (i1 && i2)
min' z1 z2 = min z1 z2
max' (Finite p1 i1) (Finite p2 i2) | p1 == p2 = Finite p1 (i1 && i2)
max' z1 z2 = max z1 z2

intersection r1 r2 = Range (max' (left r1) (left r2)) (min' (right r1) (right r2))
```

Adding `disjoint` etc is a trivial exercise.

Comment: I don't get *Your representation of ranges is incomplete as it doesn't allow one to distinguish between positive and negative infinity*. I assume that the range has only 1 dimention and null bounds would mean that any number is allowed (effectively range (-∞, +∞)). I do not want to allow infinities as values. By "an empty range" I mean that it allows everything

Also: could you represent the solution on a more C-like language or pseudocode? I don't get Haskell syntax well.

Comment: @Xeveeous *I do not want to allow infinities as values*. If you use an inferior representation for the task, you end up with inferior code. *By "an empty range" I mean that it allows everything*. That would be a misuse of the term. A range is a set of values. An empty range is an empty set of values.

Comment: @Xeveeous "I do not want to allow infinities as values" Your representation uses "no value" as a value.

Answer (score 1):

Let's solve the case where both range have bounds for some hypothetic imperative/object oriented language.

Suppose that we have implemented bound comparison to return -1,0,1 (with spaceship operator `<=>` or replace by `compare()` function) if you prefer).

```
bound self <=> bound y
    return (self.val == y.val)
        ? (self.inclusive <=> y.inclusive) // assume that false < true
        : (self.val <=> y.val);
```

Now if we test:

```
ax = a <=> x;
by = b <=> y;

If ax < by then ab is superset of xy;
If ax > by then ab is subset of xy;
If ax + by == 0 then ab equals xy;
```

Then remain the cases of intersection and disjonction, that we can't decide without another test

```
bx = b <=> x;
ay = a <=> y;
If bx == ay then ab and xy are disjoint;
Else ab and xy intersect;
```

I guess we can't do much less for finite bounds.

Now, if you introduce either +/- infinite `val`, or +/- infinite bound, problem is solved.

Of course, for infinite bound, that means that you must handle all the comparisons, which is possible by way of `<=>` operator overloading, or via double dispatching for non static type languages, but that's an easy task.

If you stick with your representation that cannot distinguish -infinity from +infinity, then you won't be able to easily perform the comparison `b <=> x` and `a <=> y` without introducing another bunch of if...